# Match zipcode and retrieve other data for that zipcode

Tags: excel, vlookup

Say I have two Sheets 1 & 2. Sheet1 has all the zipcodes - Sheet2 is missing some zipcodes but has a value that I need to place on Sheet1.

Sheet 1 has Column A: Zip; Column B: City; Column C: State;
Sheet 2 has Column A: Zip; Column B: Average $;

I want to do a Vlookup on Sheet 1 for the zip code value in Column A and see if it exists in Sheet 2 Column A. If it does exist I would like to retrieve the value in Column B on sheet 2 and place it in Column D on Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet1 D2 you paste following lookup formula and drag it Down

```
=VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```